# Passing PHP variable into a Python script not working

Tags: php, python

I am trying to call a simple python script from a php script. The result I am getting is just a single word while my actual input is a long text/sentence. The php script should return the entire sentence; it currently outputs only "The"

Python script

```
import sys
print sys.argv[1]
```

Php script

```
$var1 = "The extra sleep will help your body wash out stress hormones.";
$output = exec("C:\Python27\python.exe example.py $var1");
echo $output;
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable inputs; they are all helpful, and solved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because command line parameters are space-delimited, you have to add some quotes:

```
$output = exec("C:\Python27\python.exe example.py \"$var1\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Python script is printing the first parameter that it receives. That first parameter is "The".